# Nodejs:Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'typeCast' in null

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am making a service with sql database. I did combine 2 query to create a single query as the query's were stored in different table. But it gives an error at the last part of the code where I am trying to execute the final query.

Here is the code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 



var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'abc',

});




mysqlConnection.connect((err) => {
    if (!err)
        console.info('DB connection Succeed...!!');
    else
        console.error('DB connection Error \n Error :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
});

app.listen(4001, ()=> console.log('Express server is running on port 4001 '));



app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    if (req.method === 'PATCH'){
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});


app.get('/drawChart',(req,res)=>{

    var query1 = null;
    var query2 = null;
    var finalquery = null;
    var finquery=null;
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM t_table WHERE t_code= ?', 70, function',function(err, result){
        if (err) 
            return res.json({})
        query1=result[0].T_QUERY;
    });

    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM t_table_attr_val WHERE Table_ATTR_TYPE="GROUPBY" and t_CODE=?', 70, ', function(err, result){
        if (err) 
            return res.json({})
        query2=result[0].T_ATTR TYPE;
        finalquery=query1 + ' Group by ';
        finalquery +=query2;
        console.log(finalquery)
     });

     mysqlConnection.query(finalquery,function(err,result){
         if(err)
             return res.json({})
         console.log("result is "+ result);
     })
});
```

Here is the error message

```
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'typeCast' in null
    at Connection.query 

(C:\Users\ASUS\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:186:47)
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: we can't see what query you're executing, so how can you expect us to debug it for you? You seem to have blanked them out from your code.

Comment: i have added the query

Comment: check what you've written, I think I can see some syntax errors. `''SELECT * FROM t_table WHERE t_code= ?', 70, function'` looks wrong for example, particularly the quote marks. It helps if we have the exact code you're using, not a mis-typed version.

Comment: Also...we still can't see what the content of `finalquery` is...and that's the thing you say is the problem. So please show us what string it's building and then using for the query.

Comment: that is the only issue final query was suppose to be the combination of the result of  first two query

Comment: but i am getting no output

Comment: you mean `console.log(finalquery)` is blank? What about `query1` and `query2` individually?

Comment: It looks to me like mysqlConnection.query() is probably _asynchronous_. So likely your queries are not waiting for the earlier ones to complete before continuing. And of course they rely on the results of the earlier queries. So you can't do that. Put the calls to the subsequent queries inside the callbacks from the earlier ones, so you chain them together.

Comment: query 1 and query 2 are working perfectly i got the output of those but when i tried to combine the output and run the output as a single query then it throws the error.

Comment: Did you understand my last comment?

Comment: ok i got i wil ltry that approach.